# Undefined behavior of Lines in kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to get a line appear on a condition in my kivy (.kv) file but when I used if/else statements, the line is drawn in a way that I cannot explain (more below).

For example, if I type

```
Line: # Vertical line
        points: self.x + self.size[0]/8, self.y, self.x + self.size[0]/8, self.top if self.text == 'OR' else 0, 0, 0, 0
```

The lines becomes all weird, it becomes two segments not in the same direction but they are continued (ex: a 'L' shape or 'V' ). I don't understand, because it should ONE line not two. It would be nice if someone could enlighten me on that.

However, by guessing and trying I found a solution (I tried a bunch of different values) to my problem but I don't understand why it works

```
Line: # Vertical line
        points: self.x + self.size[0]/8, self.y, self.x + self.size[0]/8, self.top if self.text == 'OR' else self.pos[1], self.pos[0]
```

To sum it up,

- Why does self.pos[1], self.pos[0] make my line disappear
- Why does 0, 0, 0, 0 or self.pos[0], self.pos[1], self.pos[0], self.pos[1] do not make it dissapear

Comment: Are you aware that `A, B, C if cond else D, E, F` evaluates to `(A, B, C if cond else D, E, F)`, not to `(A, B, C) if cond else (D, E, F)`?

Comment: No. I am not sure to understand the difference, Do you know how to make a line disappear using those ?

Comment: Instead of tuples, explicitly write lists demarked by `[]`, and then post that code.